# Convert numpy object type to float type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```py
df.sample(3).values[:,1:].astype('float64')
>> array([[  1.31199997e+02,   1.37149994e+02,   1.31199997e+02,
          1.36320007e+02,   1.17088593e+02,   6.15015000e+05],
       [  1.35199997e+02,   1.36570007e+02,   1.34330002e+02,
          1.35639999e+02,   1.16504501e+02,   3.52835000e+05],
       [  1.31419998e+02,   1.33500000e+02,   1.30759995e+02,
          1.31779999e+02,   1.13189064e+02,   2.09805000e+05]])
```

I am reading data from csv file using pandas then convert data into `numpy.float64` but getting exponent values like `1.31199997e+02` but expected output should be normal number like `131.199997` not `1.31199997e+02`

My code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')                # reading csv
df.dtypes
>> 
Date          object
Open         float64
High         float64
Low          float64
Close        float64
Adj Close    float64
Volume         int64
dtype: object

a = df.sample(3).values[:,1:]        # get array using `dataframe.values`
a
>> array([[131.199997, 137.149994, 131.199997, 136.320007, 117.08859299999999,
        615015],
       [135.199997, 136.570007, 134.330002, 135.639999, 116.504501, 352835],
       [131.419998, 133.5, 130.759995, 131.779999, 113.18906399999999,
        209805]], dtype=object)

a = a.astype('float64')                # converting to `float64`
a
>> array([[  1.31199997e+02,   1.37149994e+02,   1.31199997e+02,
          1.36320007e+02,   1.17088593e+02,   6.15015000e+05],
       [  1.35199997e+02,   1.36570007e+02,   1.34330002e+02,
          1.35639999e+02,   1.16504501e+02,   3.52835000e+05],
       [  1.31419998e+02,   1.33500000e+02,   1.30759995e+02,
          1.31779999e+02,   1.13189064e+02,   2.09805000e+05]])
```

data.csv

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2013-05-08,135.199997,136.570007,134.330002,135.639999,116.504501,352835
2013-05-09,135.800003,138.940002,135.199997,136.259995,117.037041,952515
2013-05-10,136.199997,138.199997,135.009995,135.389999,116.289780,444045
2013-05-13,135.000000,136.000000,131.639999,132.539993,113.841843,260395
2013-05-14,131.419998,133.500000,130.759995,131.779999,113.189064,209805
2013-05-15,131.199997,137.149994,131.199997,136.320007,117.088593,615015
```

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)  suppress : bool, optional
If True, always print floating point numbers using fixed point notation, in which case numbers equal to zero in the current precision will print as zero. If False, then scientific notation is used when absolute value of the smallest number is < 1e-4 or the ratio of the maximum absolute value to the minimum is > 1e3. The default is False. So all you need to do is ```np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

As the first line under `import numpy as np`.

Comment: it's work. but i think it's not storing my number in normal format in the memory. because my end goal is to convert into pytorch `torch.from_numpy(a)` (it may be out of scope for this question but if you could help) it gave me exponent again

Comment: @anonymous Try using `torch.Tensor(a.tolist())`

Comment: `torch.Tensor(a.tolist())` not work first then find out they are using [same](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/12746) numpy behavior so i had to set `torch.set_printoptions(precision=10)` too in pytorch.

Comment: @anonymous Oh i don't know much of pytorch, happy you find a working solution :P

Answer (score 2):

`131.199997`,`1.31199997e+02` are equivalent displays of the same number.  They are both 'normal floats'.

In:

```
array([[131.199997, 137.149994, 131.199997, 136.320007, 117.08859299999999,
        615015],
       [135.199997, 136.570007, 134.330002, 135.639999, 116.504501, 352835],
       [131.419998, 133.5, 130.759995, 131.779999, 113.18906399999999,
        209805]], dtype=object)
```

each element is a Python float, and is formatted individually, regardless of the value.  Note how some strings are long, other much short.

In:

```
a = a.astype('float64')                # converting to `float64`
a
array([[  1.31199997e+02,   1.37149994e+02,   1.31199997e+02,
          1.36320007e+02,   1.17088593e+02,   6.15015000e+05],
       [  1.35199997e+02,   1.36570007e+02,   1.34330002e+02,
          1.35639999e+02,   1.16504501e+02,   3.52835000e+05],
       [  1.31419998e+02,   1.33500000e+02,   1.30759995e+02,
          1.31779999e+02,   1.13189064e+02,   2.09805000e+05]])
```

the array is displayed as a whole, using a format that will work equally well for the smaller values (`1e2`, `100`) and the larger ones (`1e5`, `100000`).  With this format it use neat columns, show the 2d array structure.

While you can control how `numpy` displays such an array, it does not change the underlying numeric values.  And for fast `numpy` calculations, you want this numeric `dtype`, not the `object` one.

Try `df.sample(3).values[:,1:-1]`.  That should just be the float values that are all around `100`.  It's the last integer column with values like `209805` that's triggering the scientific notation.

Better yet, select the columns from the dataframe, "Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close" before applying `.values`.  Those are all `float64` dtype, and the resulting array will have that dtype as well.  Select the integer `volume` column separately.  You are already treating the string/object `date` column separately.

Try:

```
a = df[df.columns[1:-1]].sample().values
```